# Want a multidimensional array but get a null pointer exception

Tags: java

```
  1 public class TestWin{
  2     public static void main(String[] args){
  3         int n;
  4         hexagon[][] board;
  5
  6         n = 4;
  7         board = new hexagon[n][n];
  8         board[0][0].value = 'R';
```

Hi. javac doesn't like what I did on line 8. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Agree. We know nothing about the hexagon type and what <Hexagon>.value means

Comment: Wtf is .value? It's not VBA :)

Comment: @SebastienLorber: `.value()` would be a method that is defined in the Hexagon class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spot on kwatford.  All you have done with line 7 is to tell java to create space for n*n Hexagon objects in a 2 dimensional array.

You will still need to call new for each of these Hexagons

Essentially, you need to replace line 7 with something like:

```
board = new Hexagon[n][n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        board[i][j] = new Hexagon();
```

Answer (score 10):

It's been a while since I've so much as looked at Java, but have you tried doing this first?

```
board[0][0] = new hexagon(); // or whatever its constructor is
```

Answer (score 5):

**Short Answer:**

As kwatford said what you need to do is this:

```
board[0][0] = new hexagon(); // or whatever its constructor is
```

**Longer Explanation:**

Just to expand further.  Your 2D array is; an array of pointers (or references in Java).  This is what one row of the array will look like immediately after this call `board = new hexagon[n][n];`:

```
    0      1      2      3      4      5       // column index, row index = 0
-------------------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |      |      |      |    // value
--- | ----- | ----- | ---------------------
    |       |       |      ...
    |       |       |
    |       |       |
    |       |       |
    |       |       v
    |       |       Null
    |       v       
    |       Null
    v
    Null (This means that it points to nothing)
```

---

You tried:

```
board[0][0].value = 'R';
```

which is the same as this:

```
null.value = 'R';
```

---

You have *initialized* your array using this line:

```
board = new Hexagon[n][n];
```

But you still need to *initialize* the elements in your array.  This would initialize the first three:

```
board[0][0] = new hexagon(); // or whatever its constructor is
board[1][0] = new hexagon(); // or whatever its constructor is
board[2][0] = new hexagon(); // or whatever its constructor is
```

Which would result in an array that looks like this:

```
    0      1      2      3      4      5       // column index, row index = 0
-------------------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |      |      |      |    // value
--- | ----- | ----- | ---------------------
    |       |       |
    |       |       |
    |       |       |
    |       |       |
    |       |       v
    |       |       An instance of type Hexigoon (what you get when you type new Hexigon)
    |       v       
    |       An instance of type Hexigon (what you get when you type new Hexigon)
    v
    An instance of type Hexigon (what you get when you type new Hexigon)
```

*I remember banging my head on the table with this exact problem two years ago.  I love stackoverflow*

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what kwatford said, initializing an array in java gives you nulls if the array type is an object. If you had a raw array, such as an array of doubles, you would start with `0` as the entry for each element of the array.